# PayPal Smart buttons patch order via PHP API

Tags: php, paypal, patch

I'm implementing Smart Buttons with Express checkout, so customers can select the delivery address on Paypal's popup. As agreed with Paypal support, I'm doing the communication with Paypal servers via PHP instead of Javascript. So in the onShippingChange event, I'm calling my server to calculate the delivery price and patch the order so Paypal updates the delivery price. The success path works fine, I need your help on error case(s).
How the patch request shall look like to instrument Paypal to display the warning that my webshop is not delivering to the selected location?  (When implementing on Javascript, this was the `return actions.reject` in the onShippingChange.)

Thanks!

This is the patch request of a successful patch:

```
{
    "path": "/v2/checkout/orders/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?",
    "body": [
        {
            "op": "replace",
            "path": "/intent",
            "value": "CAPTURE"
        },
        {
            "op": "replace",
            "path": "/purchase_units/@reference_id=='default'/amount",
            "value": {
                "currency_code": "GBP",
                "value": 265.95,
                "breakdown": {
                    "item_total": {
                        "currency_code": "GBP",
                        "value": 236
                    },
                    "shipping": {
                        "currency_code": "GBP",
                        "value": 29.95
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "verb": "PATCH",
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in the onShippingChange event, I'm calling my server to calculate the delivery price and patch the order

Great. But if the address is unsupported, your server must return the failed status in its response to that call. Based on that response, onShippingChange must `return actions.reject()` to the calling PayPal JS.

Comment: ahh. thanks. It works. So you say when all is fine, I have to return the API response from the server to the browser where the event can return it to Paypal. And if there is an error, I may return whatever I want, on client-side I need to return the actions.reject()? 
Same for createOrder and onApprove?

Comment: All I said was you need to `return actions.reject()` when the address is not valid.